# Having Problems Adding "Call" Button To iOS App

Tags: ios, button, call

Below is the action and alert view.  Why Won't This Work When The User Taps The Button?

**Alert/Action**

```
-(IBAction)myButton
{
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Call (804) 378-7120?"
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES",nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

**What To Do With User Input**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex==1)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://(804) 378-7120"]];
}
else
{
    //Do whatever you want
}
}
```

Comment: Does your class declare the `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your header?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the index of the 1st **other** button is 0. So you say

```
if(buttonIndex==0)
      {...open you URL...}  
else
      {
        NSLog(@\"cancel\");
      }
```

Comment: For Some Reason, The App Is Not Even Prompting The Alert When The User Taps The Button. Why would that be?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint before the if statement in your alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method to check whether this method is called at all?

Answer (score 0):

Per Apple documentation for [Phone Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1), the format is:

```
tel:1-408-555-5555
```

Similar to an email link, there is no `//`, and notice the use of hyphens, not parenthesis or space.

Comment: For Some Reason, The App Is Not Even Prompting The Alert When The User Taps The Button. Why would that be?

Comment: @user2516876, make sure you have the IBAction hooked up to the button and make sure you haved declared `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your header.

Answer (score 0):

use this method when the user hit the YES option.

**-(void)phoneCall
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:099123456"]];

}**

Change the number 099123456 to the number what you want to call.

Hope this result useful.

Comment: For Some Reason, The App Is Not Even Prompting The Alert When The User Taps The Button.  Why would that be?